# manifest file required version API error

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

In my application i am using:

**android theme = @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen**
but eclipse shows error.

**error is: required version (API 14) and current min is 7.**

but in another application i am using same code it doesn't shows any error ....... why?

my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: Maybe Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen is available starting from API 14? So it can't be used with API7

Comment: Check Android API version in properties of your project: Project -> Properties -> Android. But still can not launch application on Android with API version less than 14.

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:minSdkVersion="7"` to `android:minSdkVersion="14"`. It is a code compatibility checking. The theme you are using requires an android version of at least 14, therefore not compatible with versions earlier than 14.

Comment: I know that we can change android:minSdkVersion="7" to android:minSdkVersion="14"    but i mentioned above that in another project this code run without any error and i need to be stick with version 2.2 tell me any trick or code through which i can use this theme in version 7 or 2.2.

Comment: AFIAK you can't do that without recreating it using support library